# as3 access child as normal movie clip (gotoAndPlay etc.)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Still coming across hurdles with as3! This time I have created an instance of an MC from my library with addChild and now need to access this child as if it were a normal MC on the timeline but can't get it to work.

If I refer to it by instance name like:

```
this.getChildByName("mc1").gotoAndPlay(2);
```

I get the error that it can't do this to a displayObject.

If I refer to it normally as if it were just an MC on the timeline like:

```
mc1.gotoAndPlay(2);
```

Then it can't locate it (due to it being dynamically created I think.

Any guidance would be really greatly appreciated as always...

I can pop up some of my code if you would like some context.

Thanks so much!

Cam

EDIT: Thanks for the responses - I can't get this to work though?

```
var mc1:MovieClip = this.getChildByName("mc1") as MovieClip;
if(mc1) { mc1.useHandCursor = true;
mc1.buttonMode = true;
mc1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fillDriveway);
```

EDIT: Code as requested: (an example of what I want would be for mc1 onClick to gotoAndPlay)

```
import flash.display.*

pic.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,addNewPoint);

var n:Number = 0;
var joinPointsArray:Array = new Array;

function addNewPoint(e:MouseEvent):void {
    n++;
    pointNo.text = String(n);
    if(n==1){
        var nextPoint:MovieClip = new mcstart();
        addChild(nextPoint);
        nextPoint.name = "mc"+pointNo.text;
        nextPoint.x = e.target.mouseX;
        nextPoint.y = e.target.mouseY;
    }else{
        var nextPoint:MovieClip = new newPoint();
        addChild(nextPoint);
        nextPoint.name = "mc"+pointNo.text;
        nextPoint.x = e.target.mouseX;
        nextPoint.y = e.target.mouseY;
    }

    var joinPoints:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
    this.addChild(joinPoints);
    joinPointsArray.push(joinPoints);
    joinPoints.graphics.lineStyle(0.5,0xFF0000);
    joinPoints.graphics.moveTo(this.getChildByName("mc1").x, this.getChildByName("mc1").y);
    for(var i:int=2; i<=n; ++i){
        joinPoints.graphics.lineTo(this.getChildByName("mc"+i).x, this.getChildByName("mc"+i).y);
    }
}

pic.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addNewPoint);

function fillDriveway(eventObject:MouseEvent) {
    var joinPoints:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
    this.addChild(joinPoints);
    for(var p:int=0; p<(joinPointsArray.length); ++p) {
        joinPointsArray[p].alpha = 0;
    }
    this.getChildByName("mc1").alpha = 0;
    joinPoints.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF, 0.7);
    joinPoints.graphics.moveTo(this.getChildByName("mc1").x, this.getChildByName("mc1").y);
    for(var m:int=2; m<=n; ++m){
        joinPoints.graphics.lineTo(this.getChildByName("mc"+m).x, this.getChildByName("mc"+m).y);
    }
    joinPoints.name = "driveshape";
    filledDrive.text = "filled";
}

function undoit(eventObject:MouseEvent) {
    if(n > 0) {
        if(filledDrive.text.indexOf("filled") != -1) {
            this.removeChild(this.getChildAt(this.numChildren -1));
            filledDrive.text = "";
            }else{
            this.removeChild(this.getChildAt(this.numChildren -1));
            this.removeChild(this.getChildAt(this.numChildren -1));
            n--;
            pointNo.text = String(n);
        }
    }
}

undo.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, undoit);

function maskDrive(eventObject:MouseEvent) {
    if(filledDrive.text.indexOf("filled") != -1) {
        var finishA:MovieClip = new finishMC();
        this.addChild(finishA);
        finishA.x = 310;
        finishA.y = 100;
        finishA.mask = getChildByName("driveshape");
        finishA.gotoAndPlay(2);
    }
}

//BTN Actions
function btn1over(myEvent:MouseEvent) {
    btn1.gotoAndPlay(2);
}
function btn1out(myEvent:MouseEvent) {
    btn1.gotoAndPlay(11);
}
function btn2over(myEvent:MouseEvent) {
    btn2.gotoAndPlay(2);
}
function btn2out(myEvent:MouseEvent) {
    btn2.gotoAndPlay(11);
}
function btn3over(myEvent:MouseEvent) {
    btn3.gotoAndPlay(2);
}
function btn3out(myEvent:MouseEvent) {
    btn3.gotoAndPlay(11);
}

//BTN Calls
btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fillDriveway);
btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, btn1over);
btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, btn1out);
btn1.buttonMode = true;
btn1.useHandCursor = true;
btn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, maskDrive);
btn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, btn2over);
btn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, btn2out);
btn2.buttonMode = true;
btn2.useHandCursor = true;
btn3.buttonMode = true;
btn3.useHandCursor = true;
btn3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, btn3over);
btn3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, btn3out);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try to cast it to a MovieClip?

```
var mc:MovieClip = this.getChildByName("mc1") as MovieClip;
if(mc)
{
    mc.gotoAndPlay();
}
```

Comment: Or just `MovieClip(this.getChildByName("mc1")).gotoAndPlay(1);`

Comment: So should this work? Because I doesn't want to...
var mc1:MovieClip = this.getChildByName("mc1") as MovieClip;
if(mc1) {
 mc1.useHandCursor = true;
 mc1.buttonMode = true;
 mc1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fillDriveway);
}

Comment: What doesn't work? Is is not going in to the if block? Is the event not firing when you click on the movie clip? Did you try to debug and see if mc1 if the event handler added to mc1?